# Cancel Subscription with Subscriptions for woocommerce plugin

Tags: woocommerce, subscription, auto-renewing

I'm using the [Subscription for WooCommerce plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/subscriptions-for-woocommerce/) to renew subscriptions automatically,
During the unsubscription process, we want to enhance this section to persuade the user to stay subscribed. To achieve this, we use the "wps_sfw_subscription_cancel" hook to redirect the user when clicking on the "cancel" button (during unsubscription) to a page containing a descriptive message highlighting the subscription benefits, along with a "Keep My Subscription" button and a "Cancel Subscription" link.

My question is: How can I make the "Cancel Subscription" link functional and display the red message "You are unsubscribed" (the original message from the Subscriptions for Woocommerce plugin)?

I'm trying to create the same link for the "cancel" button on /my-account/show-subscription/, but it's not working.